# Ethereum Wallet syncing "stopped" when it's close to finish

Tags: ethereum

I downloaded ethereum wallet two days ago and it started to sync blocks. The syncing speed is quite fast in the beginning. Now it's close to the finish point but the syncing speed become **really slow**. I've been waiting for an afternoon but it just can't finish syncing the last 1000 blocks.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: See also, [Blocks are not being downloaded](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9002/87)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to ethereum.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The question I posted is not really an issue.

I just waited for an evening and it finally finished.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for months now. About 100 blocks left and sync not ending. Switching to "Develop" -> "Sync with light client (beta)" seems to have fixed this issue for me.  But you'd better backup your data and account files before experimenting with this. 
Disclaimer: Since this is declared 'beta' please be cautious and carefully judge if this is an option yor you.